# How to -> Visual Studio Add In Manager

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, add-in

**How do I use the Add-In Manager in Visual Studio?** Here is the problem and solution.

I want to add this [SmartPaster addin](http://inedo.com/Downloads/SmartPaster.aspx) and need to get these 3 files listed in the Add-In Manager dialog?

1. SmartPaster2010.AddIn
2. SmartPaster2010.dll
3. SmartPaster2010.xml

**Edit:** [Microsoft Add-In Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dax6cz.aspx) says:

> To install the add-in on another computer, the .addin file must be
>   placed in a location where Visual Studio checks for add-ins. These
>   locations are listed in the Options dialog box, in the Environment
>   node, on the Add-in/Macros Security page.

I went to Tools > Options > Environment > Add-In/Macro Security, checked some paths put the AddIn files in a couple of these directories, restart VS2010 but still no luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, Add-In Manager was removed in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Fortunately Scott Hanselman's effort with the NuGet solution solves all this :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Make a folder called "C:\VisualStudioPlugins"

Open up Visual Studio > Tools Menu > Options > Environment > Add-In/Macro Security > Add the path "C:\VisualStudioPlugins"

Restart Visual Studio and the add-in is listed!

<sub>ps I didn't know the answer before I asked the question and hope it helps the .Net community.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, the addin is now found, but I get an exception on both versions you refer to. Which version did you get working? (I am using VS2010 prof)

Comment: @Paul I'm using VS2010 Prem and the version for SmartPaster2010 is v1.0.3811.21587. This maybe a red herring but I've actually got two menu items in the right click context menu. One of the "Paste As" has Comment, String, StringBuilder and the other has those items plus Region and Configure. Can you post the exception and stacktrace? @Paperino (Alex Papadimoulis) might even take a look too

Comment: My Visual Studio has %VSAPPDATA%\Addins listed. Which resolves to: C:\Users\tinyRacoon\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins. I assume this is where Visual Studio is suggesting I put Addin files.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue, but it was that I was trying to use a VS Addin that was made for VS 2008.

Even with the new folder added, it wasn't picking it up in vs 2010.

By making a copy of the vs addin, and editing the .addin file, changing 9.0 to - you guessed it... 10.0... it works :) lol

Comment: I'm using the VS2015 preview and I wanted to force install a plugin that I can't live without. I had the `vsix` for the plugin, which is just a zip, so based on your answer I extracted it and edited `extension.vsixmanifest` (an XML file) to include `<VisualStudio Version="14.0">` in `<SupportedProducts>`. Worked like a charm!! Thanks so much :) :)

Comment: Thank you - for your one and only answer, its obviously helped the .Net community:)

Answer (score 5):

The product didn't come with installation instructions?

It sounds like you can probably just put the files into `%DOCUMENTS%/Visual Studio 2010/Add-Ins` (where `%DOCUMENTS%` is your documents folder, where VS likes to shove stuff by default) and reboot VS. But that's just a guess.

Comment: based on this article, your guess is as good as mine. Unfortunately no cigar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dax6cz.aspx

Comment: Yeah we should probably add some instructions for this, but for the most part what is listed in this answer is correct except the "default" add-in directory is '%DOCUMENTS%/Visual Studio 2010/Addins' (without the dash)

Comment: @John Rasch - are you sure? if so why doesn't it work? @Mark Hall pointed me to an MZTools article and he even points out there is a bug with incorrect hardcoding... Its such an easy repro. XP sp3, vs2010, the SmartPaster Addin. I'm tempted to repro this at home and put it on connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Jeremy - interesting, I just copied it into the `%VSMYDOCUMENTS%\AddIns` directory at home (Win7 Ultimate, VS2010 Ultimate) and it worked fine - I'm interested to see if it works on your home machine now!

Comment: I get that you told us what you mean by `%DOCUMENTS%` -- but it's not a real environment variable (not one that exists by default anyway) -- please don't just make things up, instead please just write it out.