# How to Add Visual Studio Add-in

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I downloaded an add-in for VS (.vsix) and went to tools>add-in manager... and it doesn't offer a browse for add-ins button. I looked on the extensions one too and didn't see anything that would let me add it.

Simple question, I know, but couldn't find anything on the net that would help me. I come from VBA.

I'm using Windows XP and VS 2010 Professional.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653436/how-to-visual-studio-2010-add-in-manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/73675/how-to-install-a-vsix-file-to-visual-studio) on Super User:

> VSIX is a Visual Studio 2010 extension installer. You must have Visual Studio 2010 in order to install them, but you should be able to install it by double-clicking the .vsix file. Alternatively you should be able to install it from within the VS Extension Manager (Tools->Extension Manager)