# Vs2010 add in , how to share with another machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I wrote a visual studio 2010 addin.

Trust me the general public does not want it, so I dont' want to upload to the Gallery.

But I want to move it to another machine (both machines are on the same network), so I have it on both.

The debug folder contains:

.dll
.pdb
.xml

I assume I have to copy them somewhere on the other machine... I've been googleing
for about 15 min and can't find the answer.

I'm sure others have solved this problem and My googling skills are just rolling 0's right now.

I'd really appreciate some help on how to do this, or better how to set up an installer, or central repository .

---

Thought I'd figured it out... but not so much...Even wrote up an answer, but I had to delete it in shame to ask more questions...

Finding this question, on stack.. I thought I had it..

[How to -> Visual Studio Add In Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653436/how-to-visual-studio-2010-add-in-manager)

I created a folder

Moved the dll, xml. pdb file there.
Copied the .AddIn file from my local machines folder here:

C:\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins

Edited the  section of that file to point to the new location of the DLL

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<Extensibility xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AutomationExtensibility">
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio Macros</Name>
        <Version>10.0</Version>
    </HostApplication>
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name>
        <Version>10.0</Version>
    </HostApplication>
    <Addin>
        <FriendlyName>GetDebugPackagesAddIn</FriendlyName>
        <Description>GetDebugPackagesAddIn </Description>
        <AboutBoxDetails>Written for Job Corps Data Center By Eric W. Brown  2010\r\nAll Rights Reserved</AboutBoxDetails>
        <AboutIconData> <snip icon data> </AboutIconData>
        <Assembly>V:\_Eric\Tools\AddIns\GetDebugPackagesAddIn\GetDebugPackagesAddIn.dll</Assembly>
        <FullClassName>GetDebugPackagesAddIn.Connect</FullClassName>
        <LoadBehavior>0</LoadBehavior>
        <CommandPreload>1</CommandPreload>
        <CommandLineSafe>0</CommandLineSafe>
    </Addin>
</Extensibility>
```

Modified my VS2010 > Tools > Options > Environment > Add-In/Macro Security >, added path to new location

Restarted VS2010... blows up when I try to load the assembly.

No Joy...

Any Help Is appreciated...

Cal-